# The requested resource (/HRportal/upcomingLeaves.do/103) is not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

url Pattern in web.xml is:

```
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

I have changed the web.file for adding

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

to solve the mapping issue not web.xml looks like:

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

So the uri matching issue has benn resolved However new issue is in picture like

The design and Layout of web-application is not displaying as It was previously.

Now it has broken. Please check the Image on this link:

http://postimg.org/image/cf80ko6in/

I wants to use both url patterns.Is it ok if I use both,will it create any problem?

server log :

```
WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/CSS/mystyle.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,384 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
12:42:40,387 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:766 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/HRportal/scripts/jquery-ui.js]
12:42:40,387 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:766 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/HRportal/CSS/Master.css]
12:42:40,388  WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/CSS/Master.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,392 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
12:42:40,390 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:766 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/HRportal/CSS/style.css]
12:42:40,388  WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/scripts/jquery-ui.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,394 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
12:42:40,394  WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/CSS/style.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,394 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: `upcomingLeaves.do` does not match `upcomingLeaves`. `{employee_id}` shoudl be `{id}`

Comment: @bart,yes,I tried but not working...any other solution..

Comment: FYI having `.do` in the middle of a URL doesn't count as an extension.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/upcomingLeaves.do/{id} and url in anchor tag ..<a class="emp-leave-action" href='<c:url value="/upcomingLeaves.do/${upComLeave.employee_id}"/>'>Accept</a>..booth are not matching that is I am getting error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request first has to be matched by the servlet container before Spring's `DispatcherServlet` can dispatch it.

Your `DispatcherServlet` seems to be mapped to

```
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

this cannot and will not match

```
/HRportal/upcomingLeaves.do/103
```

as that path does not end with `.do`.

Just change your pattern to something like

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

and have the default servlet mapping.

Comment: @user3448105 Yes, as long as they don't clash.

Comment: I already have <rui-pattern>*.do</url_-pattern> and if I write another  one that you suggested  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> is working fine but It is breaking the apps area.any solution on this?

Comment: @user3448105 What do you mean by _apps area_?

Comment: ,means the UI of web application(layout and Design) is messed up after putting <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> in web.xml.

Comment: @user3448105 Can't really help you unless you give more details. What's messed up? What is it supposed to be like? Is it related to this issue we are trying to solve right now?

Comment: @user3448105 All those images/links have a certain link, what is that and how are they handled? Just fix your links. to fit the new url-pattern.

Comment: means what?...actually I have both the url patterns so they should fit into these url patterns.

Comment: @user3448105 Open your browser's network console. Do the requests for those images receive 404 responses? What do your server logs say?

Comment: @user3448105 Look into and register a resource handler with Spring if you haven't already.